# No View Name specified in MVC Data exception found in DXA

Tags: dxa

In dxa, I created a custom area and created a Page with a single region and in that region, I want to render a component which is defined on the tridion site earlier.
But on **@Html.DxaEntities()** I found the exception

> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: No View Name specified in MVC Data.    at
> Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateMvcData(MvcData
> data, String defaultControllerName) in
> C:...\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 810    at
> Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel&
> entityModel, EntityModelData entityModelData, Type baseModelType,
> Localization localization) in
> C:\Rancher\workspace\stash\develop\net\build_webapp\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line
> 171

Please suggest as I am new on dxa and tridion

Comment: This may help: https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000012328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the "MVC Data" for Entity Models representing Component Presentations is obtained from Component Template metadata.

If you're new to DXA and Tridion, I would recommend to install the DXA Example Publications and Example Web App (using the DXA Core Module) and have a look how things are configured there.